# build app with local dll without global assembly cache

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

I built a small console application with an Oracle query, so I added a reference to `Oracle.DataAccess`. When I do a publish, and install my app other machines, I ran in an unhandled exception with a message complaining that `Oracle.DataAccess` is not in the `GAC` Global Assembly Cache. Not knowing how to fix the `GAC`, don't even know what exactly that is, I tried to add the `Oracle dll` to my application. So I created in my project a directory named `dll`, to store that dll. I removed the reference to `Oracle.DataAccess` and added a reference to the local `dll/Oracle.DataAccess.dll` .

After running publish, the dll is indeed copied.

I made sure to adjust settings in project `Properties`, tab `Publish`, button `Application Files`: remove the old entry for `Oracle.DataAccess.dl`l and checked that `dll/Oracle.DataAccess.dll` has Publish Status = Include(Auto).

However, this does not work. On another machine, the app only works if `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` is installed somewhere in `c:\oracle` .

My question is: how do I include a (this) dll to a project so that it does not have to be installed on the machine or be in c:\oracle ?

Or: what do I have to know about the `GAC` to fix it that way?

Comment: `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` just wraps unmanaged libraries that are expected to be _installed_ on the client machine. The cleanest solution is just to ensure that the Oracle Data Access Components are installed along with your application.

Comment: I think the problem is that assembly `Oracle.DataAccess` uses some depednecies - your project reference only `Oracle.DataAccess` without assemblies, that `Oracle.DataAccess` realy on. See, what assemblies is located next to oracle in original directory and try to copy them as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way we do it at my firm -- which may not be the way the works best for everyone -- is to have the third-party software installed separately.  Your application does not actually reference the third-party DLL directly, rather, it references a "runtime-callable wrapper" (RCW) that is generated automatically when you add the referenced third-party DLL your project; thus, your application is looking for, e.g., "Interop.Oracle.DataAccess.DLL" either in the GAC or in your output directory, and then in turn, the "Interop.Oracle.DataAccess.DLL" is looking for the third-party "Oracle.DataAccess.DLL" in "C:\Oracle".

The reason we install the third-party software separately is so that we can manage it independent of our own custom software.  View it like installing a windows feature in order to make something available to your custom application.

So to apply this to your situation, you would want to install Oracle Data Access via, say, an MSI that gets pushed out by the desktop or network administrator (not sure what title fits, but it's the person in charge of deploying third-party software and Windows updates).  Then, your application will be installed separately including your RCW dll in your application directory (forget about the GAC), and it should work properly.

Granted, this solution works better for applications deployed in companies to multiple desktops that are controlled by a team of IT members.  It sounds like your situation is a lot smaller in scope, so you could, of course, install the Oracle components along with your application instead of separately.  The overall idea remains the same, though: they should still be deployed to their "natural" place (c:\Oracle) and then referenced by the RCW in your output directory.

Comment: Never thought of that DLL referencing other DLLs. In linux there is a tool `ldd` (wordplay on DLL???) that shows you in a very simple way all library dependencies including sub-dependencies. I wished windows had something similarly simple.

Comment: Well, to be fair, what we're talking about is not quite a DLL referencing another DLL although that's quite common -- .NET framework itself is just a set of DLLs, so when you build your application, you're doing just that.  It's more like wrapping rather than referencing in the traditional sense.  .NET Interoperability is a beast of its own, and a very vast topic.  You should check out Sysinternals "Process Explorer" (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).  It has the ability to show you all the DLLs used by a process.  It's quite enlightening.

Comment: Using that, you can see that your "simple" application is actually referencing 10's or 100's of DLLs because each DLL is, itself, referencing their own DLLs and so on.

Comment: @Roland -- see comments.

Comment: +1 Thanks for refering to that tool, it may be very useful for fixing dll problems